# Using Prerender.io how to redirect the crawlers to our fragmented site?

Tags: reactjs, prerender, google-crawlers

Currently we are using prerender-node to crawl the HTML content. It is working only when we add "_escaped_fragment_=" to our url. How to see the crawled HTML content without adding hash tag.

Example:
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

Can we able to see HTML content without "_escaped_fragment_=" ?

Example:
http://www.example.com

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, so SO community can help you?
Do you want to see what web crawler sees? If so, you can navigate to `_escaped_fragment_=` page in browser.

Comment: I can able to see the html content in page view source when we add "?_escaped_fragment_=" to my url. Otherwise it is not showing in page view source.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed prerender-node behavior. You can fork and change its source code to make it render HTML content to your custom url instead of `_escaped_fragment_=` param OR check [prerender-node docs](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node) and use customization parameters from there.

You can find what changes you can apply to source code in comments to this answer.

Comment: I don't find any customization parameter in prerender-node documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node/blob/f07e9f5ac3aea8b24888944e468541df1064cb4f/index.js#L140
Change this line in prerender-node source code, then you'll be able to see html content. I don't understand **why** you even need this though. Maybe [whitelist](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node#whitelist) parameter is what you need.

Comment: Can you tell what i need to change from this statement.  if(parsedQuery && parsedQuery['_escaped_fragment_'] !== undefined) isRequestingPrerenderedPage = true;

Comment: Just remove parsedQuery['escaped_fragment'] !== undefined

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much